# MySQL: Update all rows in 2 table matching results of another query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table with same id, i'd like to change the id for both table with the value from 2nd table.

Ex:
Table_1

```
ID    TITLE    CONTENT    AUTHOR
 1     aaa      abcd        aaaa
 2     aaa      abcd        aaaa
 3     aaa      abcd        aaaa
 4     aaa      abcd        aaaa
```

Table_2:

```
ID post_id    post_title    pos_key    value
 1    1        aaa            a_key        2
 2    1        aaa            E_key     2000
 3    2        aaa            b_key        3
 4    2        aaa            b_key        3
 5    2        aaa            E_key     2500
 6    3        aaa            c_key        4
 7    3        aaa            d_key        5
 8    3        aaa            E_key     3000
 9    4        aaa            f_key        6
10    4        aaa            E_key     3500
```

How can i update all Table_1 ID and Table_2 post_id from the value of Table_2 which have  E_key on post_key row ?.

This is what i want for my both table:

Table_1

```
  ID   TITLE    CONTENT     AUTHOR
2000     aaa      abcd        aaaa
2500     aaa      abcd        aaaa
3000     aaa      abcd        aaaa
3500     aaa      abcd        aaaa
```

Table_2:

```
ID   post_id    post_title    pos_key    value
 1      2000     aaa            a_key        2
 2      2000     aaa            E_key     2000
 3      2500     aaa            b_key        3
 4      2500     aaa            b_key        3
 5      2500     aaa            E_key     2500
 6      3000     aaa            c_key        4
 7      3000     aaa            d_key        5
 8      3000     aaa            E_key     3000
 9      3500     aaa            f_key        6
10      3500     aaa            E_key     3500
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What have you tried?  A good start is to write a `SELECT` query which pulls both the old and new values; from there it's usually simple to rewrite it as an `UPDATE`.  I believe this will do it:

```
UPDATE T1
SET ID = T2.Value
FROM    Table_1 AS T1
    INNER JOIN Table_2 AS T2 ON T1.ID = T2.post_id
WHERE
    T2.pos_key = 'E_key'

UPDATE T2
SET post_id = NewIDs.Value
FROM    Table_2 AS T2
    INNER JOIN Table_2 AS NewIDs ON T2.post_id = NewIDs.post_id
WHERE
    NewIDs.pos_key = 'E_key'
```

My apologies if my MySQL is off, I usually work in MS SQL.

Comment: Thank you for your help, unfortunately both query not working, the first one only work with select query... the second one are not working with select and update.

Comment: "Not working" does not tell me anything useful.  Are you getting an error?  Fewer records updated than expected?  None?  Records updated differently from what you expected?

Comment: well, i try this query and it's working. 

UPDATE Table_1 AS T1
INNER JOIN Table_2 AS T2 ON T1.ID = T2.post_id
SET T1.ID = T2.Value
WHERE T2.pos_key = 'E_key'

UPDATE Table_2 AS T2
INNER JOIN Table_2 AS NewIDs ON T2.post_id = NewIDs.post_id
SET T2.post_id = NewIDs.Value
WHERE NewIDs.pos_key =  'E_key'

Thank you